# Convert List[String] into ValidationNEL[String, A] in a function

Tags: scala, types, scalaz

I have a function with the following signature

```
def reject[A](errors: List[String]): ValidationNEL[String, A]
```

Since this is a reject method, the type `A` would never be returned but I need it to be reflected in order to match the signature.  I was messing around with type lambdas to get my desired result as follows:

```
errors.map(Failure[String, A](_).liftFailNel).sequence[({type l[a] = ValidationNEL[String, a]})#l, A]
```

This uses the type `List[A]` (or appears to), rather than my desired type `A`.  Is there a standard way to derive the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `errors` may be an empty `List`, and you are constraining yourself to have no value of type `A`, I don't think you can write this as a total function. To write this type signature, you would need to cheat by pretending the empty list case does not exist, e.g.

```
def reject[A](errors: List[String]): ValidationNEL[String, A] =
  Failure(errors.toNel.get) // bad!
```

---

**Edit:** As Apocalisp pointed out, you can of course make this a total function, by introducing an error for the empty list. But I would only do that if `errors` is computed at runtime, and I suspect this is not your use case, as it would lead to silly errors such as:

```
def reject[A](errors: List[String]): ValidationNEL[String, A] =
  Failure(errors.toNel getOrElse NonEmptyList("Error: There were no errors!"))
```

---

Why not pass the `errors` as a `NonEmptyList` instead - presumably you only use this function if you have errors to use at compile time.

```
def reject[A](errors: NonEmptyList[String]): ValidationNEL[String, A] =
  Failure(errors)
```

You can make this terser to use by copying the signature of `NonEmptyList.apply` (and specialising it to `String`):

```
def reject[A](h: String, t: String*): ValidationNEL[String, A] =
  Failure(NonEmptyList(h, t: _*))
```

Let's try it out:

```
scala> reject("foo", "bar", "baz")
res0: scalaz.package.ValidationNEL[String,Nothing] = Failure(NonEmptyList(foo, bar, baz))
```

Comment: That's true, I didn't think of that (duh). That would be useful if `errors` is computed at runtime, but I assumed he would be writing out  literals in his code. I doubt "oops, you forgot to write the error in teh codes" would be a useful error at runtime, then.

Comment: I had made the change to the Non-empty list in my code right before I saw your answer Ben - I agree that is the best solution.

Comment: where is the .toNel method defined? I can't find it :(